# Debian Linux: Find Application that generates lots of Incoming Traffic

Tags: linux, debian, network-traffic

Is there any way to find out which application on a server is responsible for incoming traffic?

I have a debian linux server that has a lot of incoming traffic and would like to know if someone managed to hack his way into it or if there's a faulty web-application (apache2 + PHP) and I just have to fix a bug.

Any suggestions? Applications I need to know about? "Long Time Network Monitors"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) and [pktstat](http://www.adaptive-enterprises.com.au/~d/software/pktstat/) to help visualise your network traffic. They are both in the apt repositories.

They will show you all incoming/outgoing connections, services that they are connected to, traffic bandwidth for each connection, ipaddress/named entries and much more. That will help you track down the offending app (with some help from netstat).

Have fun!

Comment: pktstat did it for me. Helped me to find out that my provider charged me for traffic of another server, too - due to a routing problem.

Comment: glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

For specific php/apache monitoring, [`mod_status`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) will show you a web accessible list of all current apache connections. To see all PHP traffic, you can monitor from the command line using

> `watch -n1 "/etc/init.d/httpd fullstatus | grep .php | egrep \"GET|POST\""`

Don't forget to prevent outside access with

```
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from .foo.com
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

For an all round traffic stats, except iptraf you can try bandwithd. I used it before and it is able to produce nice graphs for traffic based on source <-> target ip, breakdown of traffic by protocols etc. All of this in real time ;) It is included in both debian and ubuntu.

Comment: I can't find bandwithd in debian. Any hints where to look?